# Creating Modules in chisel dynamically and at the same time passing dynamic parameters to those modules

Tags: scala, chisel

Consider this example

```
for(x <- 0 until numberOfHWBlocks){
    val hw_block = Module(new HW_BLOCK(x)(p :Parameters)).io
}
```

Each time this creates a new module according to whatever x is. What I want is that I do not want to declare val hw_block each time as a separate entity inside the for loop as this value overrides the previous value. I want a seq of these modules stored in a single val. Something like this

```
for( x <- 0 until numberOfHWBlocks){
    hw_block(x) = Module(new HW_BLOCK(x)(p :Parameters)).io
}
```

where hw_block is defined as a Seq outside the for loop

```
val hw_block = Seq.fill(numberOfHWBlocks){//What do I have to instantiate here??//}
```

Comment: `Seq.tabulate(numberOfHWBlocks)(x => Module(new HW_BLOCK(x)(p :Parameters).io))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered tabulate

```
val hw_block = Seq.tablulate(numberOfHardHWBlocks) { x =>
  Module(new HW_BLOCK(x)(p :Parameters)).io
}
```

`tabulate` is like file but gives you the ability to distinguish which element is
being instantiated

Note: I think your syntax for the Module creation is slightly wrong. I think it should be `Module(new HW_BLOCK(...)).io`, this creates the module then returns the io bundle for reference in HW_Block

Answer (score 1):

`tabulate` as in the comment and Chick's response is the best answer, but I'll provide a little more context because `tabulate` is kind of a special case for when you want to construct from a range of Integers starting from `0`.

Say I had a `Seq` of `Strings` that I wanted to construct a `Seq` of Modules from, how would I do it? Many who are new to Chisel and Scala will think of a `for` loop and mutation. While in Scala we generally prefer to use immutable types and functional programming, you can still accomplish this with mutation:

```scala
val myModules = ArrayBuffer[MyModule]()
val myParams = Seq("foo", "bar")
for (param <- myStrings) {
  myModules += Module(new MyModule(param)) // .io if you just want the io ports
}
```

This is more akin to your original idea, so how can I make this more functional in a way similar to `Seq.fill` and `Seq.tabulate`? We can take the `Seq` of parameters we wish to pass, and `map` on it:

```scala
val myParams = Seq("foo", "bar")
val myModules = myParams.map(param => Module(new MyModule(param)))
```

As I said previously, `Seq.tabulate` is a special case of this more general `map` pattern where you have a range of integers, thus your case could alternatively be expressed as:

```scala
(0 until numberOfHWBlocks).map(x => Module(new HW_BLOCK(x)(p: Parameters).io))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this while Creating input and output pins? Say I have a val ip = Input(Vec(numberOfHWBlocks, new someNewBundle(p : Parameters)(x))) where x can be some parameter sent dynamically?

Comment: That's possible but more complicated. You can't use `Vec` because `Vec` requires that all of its elements have the same type, but you can do this with a `Record`. Fair warning, it's a more advanced API, I'd suggest opening another StackOverflow question about it.